# Wireshark won't launch, Segmentation Fault, Kali Linux

Tags: wireshark, kali-linux, segmentation-fault

Wireshark won't launch when logged in as root or normal user. I receive segmentation fault in the terminal window every time.

Output from the terminal (the same for both root and normal user):

```
root@kali:~# wireshark
Segmentation fault
root@kali:~#
```

Output from gdb:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/wireshark 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe135e700 (LWP 1799)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd5d10700 (LWP 1800)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd550f700 (LWP 1801)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcc871700 (LWP 1802)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc7fff700 (LWP 1803)]

**Thread 1 "wireshark" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff0ab175b in wtap_encap_string ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiretap.so.6**

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff0ab175b in wtap_encap_string ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwiretap.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff445af9d in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwireshark.so.8
#2  0x00007ffff4ccf38f in register_all_protocols ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwireshark.so.8
#3  0x00007ffff4172868 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwireshark.so.8
#4  0x00007ffff414ddc7 in epan_init ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwireshark.so.8
#5  0x00005555556a26fa in main ()
```

Any suggestions welcome. Searched the internet for some solutions but came up with nothing. Thanks.

Comment: sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: I have tried it already and again today. Unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 7):

I had this same error with version 2.2.5, I ended up completely removing wireshark

```
sudo apt-get remove wireshark
```

I then reinstall the qt version which seemed to fix it, though I am not sure why

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark-qt
```

I think it is something in the current version that is messing things up, but I cannot say for certain

Comment: Worked for me, on kali linux provided by offensive security for pwk course. Noticed that when installing `wireshark-qt` the packages selected for installation by aptitude is `qt5-gtk-platformtheme, wireshark`. Maybe just adding the former can fix? 
Also, diffing the output of `wireshark -v` before and after I see that my wireshark version bumped from 2.2.0 to 2.2.7, GLib from 2.48.1 to 2.52.3, gcc from 6.1.1 to 6.3.0, and remaining info stayed the same.